# Draw slanted line pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a code to put the black arrows on the yellow line, I do it by coordinates, the problem is that the other line does not work correctly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

coordinates = [['Row', 0, 6.0, 5, 8.5, 0.42],
               ['Row', 5, 8.5, 10, 6.0, 0.30]]

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(coordinates)): 

    xo = coordinates[i][1]
    yo = coordinates[i][2]
    xf = coordinates[i][3]
    yf = coordinates[i][4]

    wd = abs(coordinates[i][5])
    steps = 1

    plt.plot((xo, xf), (yo, yf), color='orange', linewidth=5) 
    
    plt.plot((10, 10), (9, 9)) 
    plt.plot(2.5, 2.5)
    
    for arr in np.arange(xo, xf + 1e-9, steps):
        slope = (yf-yo) / (xf-xo)
        yep = slope * arr + yo
        plt.arrow(arr, yep + wd, 0, -wd, color='black', linewidth=1)        
        
plt.show()
```

Maybe it's a bad use of the loop, but the logic is that they are positioned according to the slope equation of a line.

To illustrate, I have the following graph.

[image]

I seek to make it so.

[image]

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to subtract `xo` from `arr`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

coordinates = [['Row', 0, 6.0, 5, 8.5, 0.42],
               ['Row', 5, 8.5, 10, 6.0, 0.30]]
for row in coordinates:
    xo, yo, xf, yf, wd = row[1:]
    wd = abs(wd)
    steps = 1
    plt.plot((xo, xf), (yo, yf), color='orange', linewidth=5)
    plt.plot((10, 10), (9, 9))
    plt.plot(2.5, 2.5)
    for arr in np.arange(xo, xf + 1e-9, steps):
        slope = (yf - yo) / (xf - xo)
        yep = slope * (arr - xo) + yo
        plt.arrow(arr, yep + wd, 0, -wd, color='black', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]